# Can't access relationships with appServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

In my header i need to use some relationships. I was defined the variables in appserviceprovider. Like that:

```
$v_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $v_group->id)->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
$view->with('categories', $v_categories);
```

in the blade when i use foreach with "categories" its working like a charm. 
But when i tried to use it with relationship it throws an exception.

```
    Exception
Property [children] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

This is my relationship:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

My question is how can i use children function and "categories" eloquent (from appServiceProvider) in the blade? 
There is a problem. But i can't figure it out why? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because `$categories` is a collection (even just of one item, as a result of being a `hasMany` relationship) and you'll need to either loop over them in your view or use `first()` instead of `get()` in your service provider (if you're only expecting one).

Comment: But i need to use all categories. For each category i need to use children function and get all children too. First is not a solution as i thought.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to loop over all of your categories in your view :)

Comment: Now i got the point. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great :) I've added it as an answer. Please accept when you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `hasMany` relationship in combination with `get()` is returning a `Collection` instance which contains an array of `Category` items.

So you'll need to loop over these to address them individually.

In your view, try something like this:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->children as $child_category)
        {{ $child_category->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```